# Boto3 get_waiter does not stop and start instance correctly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

Problem:
Hello I'm trying to stop and start instances in the same lambda function. I'm using waiters, however the code above only stops the instance, but doesn't start it back up as it does not wait for the stop. Please help me correct the code, thank you

Code:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  
    ids = ['i-xxxx']

    #stop Instance
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=ids)
    waiter = ec2.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
    waiter.wait(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name','Values': ['stopped']}])
    print("instance is stopped")
  
    #start Instance
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=ids)
    waiter = ec2.get_waiter('instance_running')
    waiter.wait(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name','Values': ['running']}])
    print("instance is started and running")
```

Comment: I believe that the waiter code should be: `waiter.wait(InstanceIds=ids)`

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment, you haven't told the waiter which instance to wait for.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback, that is the issue and is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adjusted your code and tested in Cloud Shell.  For more details on waiters you should check out the documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceRunning)

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  
    ids = ['i-0d01a6288188f08ce']

    #stop Instance
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=ids)
    instance_stopped_waiter = ec2.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
    instance_stopped_waiter.wait(InstanceIds=ids)
    print("instance is stopped")
        
    #start Instance
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=ids)
    instance_runner_waiter = ec2.get_waiter('instance_running')
    instance_runner_waiter.wait(InstanceIds=ids)
    print("instance is started and running")
```

Comment: This solution works. Thank you so much